# Quantum multi valued decision diagrams

Tags: quantum-computing

I recently came across the paper "QMDD: A Decision Diagram Structure for Reversible and Quantum Circuits" by Thornton and Miller. It deals with a way of compactly representing transformation matrix for a given quantum circuit or a quantum gate. I tried very hard to construct a QMDD of a Toffoli gate but I failed. Then I realized maybe I didn't understand QMDDs.

Can anyone please explain me QMDDs and a way to construct a QMDD for a given circuit or gate?